# Obtain original struct/class name during C++ template instantiation

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, static-assert

```
template<typename T> struct S {};
template<typename T> struct R {};

int main() {
  typedef S<double> s1;
  typedef S<int> s2;
  typedef R<int> s3;
  static_assert(xxx<s1, s2>::value,
                "No, assertion must not be raised");
  static_assert(xxx<s2, s3>::value,
                "Yes, assertion must be raised");
}
```

So, I want `xxx<s1, s2>::value` to return true while `xxx<s2, s3>::value` to return false during compile-time.

Is the existence of xxx impossible in C++?
Or, is the existence of xxx theoretically possible in C++ but possibly no one has done it yet?

Comment: So, `xxx<T, U>::value` is `true` iff `T` and `U` are specializations of the same template?

Comment: @Quentin: yes :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use two specialisations​ that use template template parameters to perform this "matching":

```
template<
  typename T,
  typename V>
struct xxx;

template<
 template <class> class A,
 template <class> class B,
 typename X,
 typename Y>
struct xxx<A<X>, B<Y>> {
  static constexpr const int value = false;
};


template<
 template <class> class U,
 typename X,
 typename Y>
struct xxx<U<X>, U<Y>> {
  static constexpr const int value = true;
};
```

[With your code on ideone](http://ideone.com/3ShRwM)

Note: For it to be a real type trait you should not set `value` manually, but derive from `std::integral_constant` (`std::true_type` or `std::false_type`). Above is just a quick mockup I did on my phone.

Comment: What is *constexpr const*?

Comment: Are you _sure_ you need _two_ specializations?

Comment: @HWalters No, but with two specialisations it gives an error if it was used with types that are not instantiations of some templates. I'd prefer it that way, because now that trait does only *one* thing (same templates?) and not two (templates? same templates?).

Comment: @HWalters Like here: http://ideone.com/USMD1Q "error: implicit instantiation of undefined template [..]"

Comment: When I use `xxx` in the following way by first including `ratio` header: `int main() { typedef std::ratio<7, 8> r1; typedef std::ratio<12, 9> r2; static_assert(xxx<r1, r2>::value, "No, assertion shan't be raised"); }`, compiling it with `g++ -std=c++14 -o mwe mwe.cpp` gives: `error: incomplete type 'xxx<std::ratio<7l, 8l>, std::ratio<12l, 9l> >' used in nested name specifier`. Any idea?

Comment: Ops, sorry, my bad, I need to tweak your solution to have two parameters. Let me try it first.

Comment: I will open up a new thread to address the non-type template parameter. As for the initial problem, your solution works with `g++ -std=c++14`. Thanks.

Comment: I manage to utilize your strategy in the following way, so I won't open a new thread: `template<typename T, typename V> struct xxx : std::false_type {}; template<typename U> struct xxx<U, U> : std::true_type {}; template<template <typename, typename> class U, typename X1, typename X2, typename Y1, typename Y2> struct xxx<U<X1, X2>, U<Y1, Y2>> : std::true_type {}; template<template <intmax_t, intmax_t> class U, intmax_t X1, intmax_t X2, intmax_t Y1, intmax_t Y2> struct xxx<U<X1, X2>, U<Y1, Y2>> : std::true_type {};`

Answer (score 1):

Something like `same_base_template`:

```
#include <type_traits>
template<class A, class B>
struct same_base_template : std::false_type{};

template<template<class...> class S, class... U, class... V>
struct same_base_template<S<U...>, S<V...>> : std::true_type{};
```

#### Edit:

And a third specialization since you are using non-type template arguments (`std::ratio`):

```
template<class T, template<T...> class S, T... U, T... V>
struct same_base_template<S<U...>, S<V...>> : std::true_type{};
```

### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dhDU4gOfiN2DD6UC)

This uses `true_type`and `false_type` from `type_traits` so we don't need to write a `constexpr bool value` ourselves. I used a variadic template here because it was slightly more generic and took only a few more keystrokes to do. For your specific use case, you don't need them)

Comment: I'm all ears for a better name than `same_base_template`.

Comment: When I use `same_base_template` in the following way by first including header `ratio`: `int main() { typedef std::ratio<7, 8> r1; typedef std::ratio<12, 9> r2; static_assert(same_base_template<r1, r2>::value, "No, assertion shan't be raised"); }`, compiling it with `g++ -std=c++14 -o mwe mwe.cpp` raises the static assertion `error: static assertion failed: No, assertion shan't be raised`, which should not be the case. Any idea?

Comment: @TadeusPrastowo: This is because `std::ratio` is accepting non-type template arguments (the integer values for the ratio). This is slightly different than what I expected, so I added another specialization. I've updated my post. See the new demo.

Comment: Now `g++ -std=c++14` says `error: template parameters not deducible in partial specialization:
 struct same_base_template<S<U...>, S<V...>> : std::true_type{};`. The error does not go away when I use `-std=c++1z` as in the demo. Any idea?

Comment: @TadeusPrastowo: Hmm, it seems C++14 cannot handle this in clang or gcc. Using C++17 via the wandbox link, though, neither of them complain. Working on a C++14 fix.